# Работа с файлами

Tags: c

Почему у меня buff[0] выводит последнюю строку файла, и как можно сделать, чтобы все элементы массива были доступны за пределами цикла?

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("test.db", "rb");

int i = 0;
char str[126];
char *buff[126];

while (!feof(fp)) {
    if (fgets(str, 126, fp)) {
        buff[i] = str;
    }
    i++;
}

printf("%sn", buff[0]);
```

Comment: @badsanta, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Сохранять их. Потому что строки читаются в str, а вот канитель с buff -- вообще за пределами разума. Все элементы buff[i] равны str. (И хорошо, если fgets будет вызываться меньше 126 раз)

Копирования содержимого str в buff[i]=str не происходит, да и некуда там копировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему у меня buff[0] выводит
> последнюю строку файла

Потому что очередную строку Вы читаете в `char str[126]`, соответственно предыдущее значение массива `str` затирается. `Buf[0]` по сути указывает туда же, куда и `Buf[i]` - на `str`, в котором лежит последняя прочитанная строка.

> как можно сделать, чтобы все элементы
> массива были доступны за пределами
> цикла?

Читать в разные строки

```
while(!feof(fp)) 
{ 
  if(fgets(str, 126, fp))
  {
    char* curr  = malloc(126); // создать новую строку
    memcp(curr, str, 126); // скопировать в нее прочитанное содержимое
    buff[i++]=curr; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: >>memcp(curr, str, 126); // скопировать в нее прочитанное содержимое
memcpy:) символ y - забыл, а так все работает, спасибо.

Comment: А зачем именно 126 ? Что, strlen() уже не работает ?

Comment: 126 для более доходчивого объяснения.

Answer (score 0):

buff[i] = strdup(str) решит Вашу проблему.

Внутри strdup() делает malloc(), так что может понадобиться освобождать память.

Comment: strdup не входит в стандарт вроде бы.

Comment: У меня с любыми libc работала. Если где-то ее нет, то дописать не проблема.